# TEMP FIX - Build and Upload iOS application Expo (Without Application Loader)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

When Application Loader isn't a part of XCode 11 after Sept 20 anymore how should we upload the application?

Comment: Looks like it's been fixed in the latest version of expo-cli. https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/927#issuecomment-540049932

Comment: good to know that, will check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Steps to follow:**

1. Download the build created by `expo build:ios`
2. run the following command `xcrun altool --upload-app -f pathtothefile.ipa -u youremail@apple.com`

   > **Password:** This isn't your app store or any other apple-related password, it's the App-Specific Password and you need to generate it first.

   Can be found at https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage
3. Should return with a success message `No errors uploading '/path/to/your/package.ipa'`
4. You can view you build in **[App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/) -> Your App -> Activity**

Comment: expo build:ios gives me the error that there is already a profile with the same name:
"validationUserMessage":"Multiple profiles found with the name 'project-name AppStore'.  Please remove the duplicate profiles and try again."}]}


 (which makes sense because I want to upgrade the previous build). How can I upgrade the build to version 2?

Comment: Have lost touch to the deployment thing, but will take a look and will let you know.